# What is a good data structure and tool for storing and working with 200,000+ time series?

Tags: python, data-structures, pandas, statistics, time-series

**EDIT:** Describing the data a little better.

I have a large dataset, currently with 200,000+ data points, but will be even larger soon. The data are number of downloads an article (webpage) has received on a daily basis since publication. I'm not interested in the calendar day, but I am interested in number of days since publication.

So the data looks a something like this at the moment:

```
id,country,subject,publication_date,day1,day2,day3,day4,day5....day1000
1,canada,science,2008-01-01,0,3,12,5,33,45,66,3,3.....
2,usa,english,2014-03-15,1,3,14
```

Where each of those numbers represents number of downloads for a day, with each column being a day since publication. Each row, therefore, has different number of columns, since some articles have been around longer than others.

What would be a good data structure to use for this data that allows the following:

- easy filtering by country or subject
- easy filtering by "at least X downloads in X days"
- easy extraction (for regressions or clustering) of the download data

I am familiar (though not entirely) with Python Pandas, and I've used it for some data manipulation in the past. It seemed like a good candidate for the job, especially if I stored my data as a TimeSeries. I manipulated my data to a DF with a TimeSeries index for a single article, something like the following.

**note:** this is a TimeSeries for a single ID, I need a structure for 200,000+ articles.

```
date  downloads
2000-01-01   3
2000-01-02   2
2000-02-08   1
2000-02-09   1
2000-02-10   2
```

But not sure where to go from there. I thought of re-centering all the times to start from a fixed date, so the datasets could be combined. But then I'd end up with a column for each data point (i.e., 200,000+ columns) and a separate DataFrame to store the id's and their characteristics (subject/country).

Would that make sense? Is there a problem with so many columns? Is there a better way?

**EDIT:** Preference would be to keep using python, but not wedded to Pandas. If it has to be another language/tool, its OK. I will learn!

Comment: This is the sort of problem that a traditional relational database is meant for.  However, if disk space is a concern, or if you want particularly easy integration with numpy and pandas, PyTables is also very well suited to this. http://www.pytables.org

Comment: This is a straightforward multi-index and groupby, storing in HDFStore (backed by PyTables) is good for storage, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables

Comment: in either case, what would be your choice for storing the download data? Would you put it all in one cell? Remember I need to be able to sum the first X days.

Comment: you can add a column for the publication name, so your 'keys' are date,pubname, with the value of the downloads, 2-levels.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my data. Will edit my question to emphasize what I think you're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jeff and @Joe Kington. I ended up going with a MultiIndex'ed Series backed with an HDF5 store. Its working well.